# Hive QL Difference between two closest elements in a column

Tags: sql, hiveql

Let's say I have a very simple table like this:

```
ID: Integer
A    4
A    9
A    2
B    4 
B    7
B    3
```

And I want to groupBy(ID). What would be an appropriate query that tells me the minimum difference - like this

```
ID: MIN_DIF:
A    2
B    1
```

Simplicity of the query right now is more important than efficiency, but both the most basic and the most efficient query would be appreciated.

Sidenote: Finding the average distance would be a bonus, but I need min first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `lag()` or `lead()`:

```
select id, min(int - prev_int)
from (select t.*, lag(int) over (partition by id order by int) as prev_int
      from t
     ) t
group by id
where prev_int is not null;
```

An alternative method avoids window functions but would probably have much worse performance is:

```
select t.id, min(t2.integer - t.integer)
from t join
     t t2
     on t.id = t2.id 
where t2.integer > t.integer
group by t.id;
```

Comment: The[apache language manual](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF) doesn't include lag or lead?

Comment: @knowads . . . Check here:  https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+WindowingAndAnalytics.